# Include file with variable

Tags: php, html, css

I'm building a sales system in PHP, but I want to include a .xml file, based on a variable. 
So the variable i've made is

```
$date = date("y-m-d D")
```

**output**: `16-11-18 Fri.`

I've load an .xml via:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load(YourXmlFile);
```

But I want to replace 'YourXmlFile' with the value $date returns.

Does Anyone knows how this works?

Comment: have you tried something amon the lines of `$xmlDoc->load($date)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load($date . '.xml');
```

The file in this case would be 16-11-18 Fri.xml

Answer (score 0):

You got

> $date = date("y-m-d D") output: 16-11-18 Fri

just append ".xml" extension, so file name will be

> $filename = $date.".xml";

Then pass $filename into your function

> $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); $xmlDoc->load($filename);

I'm not sure you want to ask this only but from your question we can understand this only.